# python pandas print element of dataframe

Tags: printing, pandas, element

I have a pandas data frame named country_codes:

```
>>> country_codes.head(3)

       COUNTRY FIPS ISO2 ISO3

0  Afghanistan   AF   AF  AFG

1      Albania   AL   AL  ALB

2      Algeria   AG   DZ  DZA
```

given a particular fips code:

```
>>> fips = 'RS'
```

I select the country name corresponding to that fips code:

```
>>> country = country_codes[country_codes['FIPS']==fips]['COUNTRY']
```

and print it:

```
>>> print(country)

201    Russia

Name: COUNTRY, dtype: object
```

I want to use that country name in the title of a matplotlib plot. I want the country name only. I do not want the index number or the line that says Name: COUNTRY, dtype: object.
How do I get the name only?

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a [series from indexing the dataframe](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#basics)

```py
>>> country = country_codes[country_codes['FIPS']==fips]['COUNTRY']
>>> type(country)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

For a Series, [selection by position](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#selection-by-position):

```py
>>> country.iloc[0]
'Russia'
```

Comment: in other words, I should say                                         country  = country_codes[country_codes['FIPS']==fips]'COUNTRY'].iloc[0]      >>> print(country)
Russia                                                          right?

Answer (score 1):

I think create a series with FIPS as the key and COUNTRY as the value will make the code simpler:

```
fips = pd.Series(df["COUNTRY"].values, index=df["FIPS"])
```

then you can get the country by:

```
fips["AL"]
```

Comment: Note: this assumes that country codes are unique (though probably a safe assumption).

Comment: This is the way to do it. It is dramatically faster code than navigating the dataframe. One alternate approach to getting the 'COUNTRY' Series indexed by 'FIPS' would be `df.set_index('FIPS')['COUNTRY']`

Answer (score 0):

if you have pandas data series , and how to access via index is as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
data=np.array([176.2,158.4,167.6,156.2,161.4])
heights=pd.Series(data,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
print(heights['s2'])
```